# Strange effect when creating a ListView

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I have noticed a strange effect when I create a Listview.

When I create a ListView without also creating a Button, the selected item in the ListView have a dotted border. However, when I also create a Button, the ListView selected item don't have a dotted border anymore. This only happens when I have a manifest file that enables common controls 6:

[image]

This is the code I used to create the Window and ListView and Button:

```
// Create Window
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 261, 172, 394, 284, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

// Create ListView
HWND hListView = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, "", WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 232, 190, hWnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

// Create Button
HWND hButtonRefresh = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "OK", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 10, 200, 110, 25, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

**Note:** I don't have a problem with this effect, I just want to understand why it is happening!

Comment: The "dotted border" indicates the listview has input focus. Presumably whichever control is created last gets input focus by default, meaning when you have a button it has it instead of the listview.

Comment: ^ this. As can be seen with the OK being blue-bordered.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter But in both images, I am clicking on the ListView item, so the ListView has the focus and not the Button.

Comment: Focus rectangles are hidden by default in Windows these days until you actually use the keyboard. You can use the `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` message to change this.

Comment: Also see: [Untangling the confusingly-named WM_UPDATEUISTATE and WM_CHANGEUISTATE messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/16/10419105.aspx)

Comment: By default when you launch an application something is selected, if it has buttons  you can code which one to select

Comment: Try adding another button and listview to see the effects.

Answer (score 1):

It's just because the button has the focus and the list view lost it, click on the list view and the dots should reappear.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Even when I click on any ListView item, the style stays the same.

Comment: @paul It's been explained what's happening in the comments. What more don't you understand? Why are you wasting a bounty on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dotted border is indicating the default control. In the second screenshot go to the Properties of the button and set Default Button to false and then you should see the dotted border around the text like in the first screenshot.

To do this open the dialog in Resources view, select the button and choose Properties from the right-button mouse menu. In the Properties window you should see Default Button in the Behavior section - just change it to False.

Alternatively in code try something like this:-

```
DWORD style = m_BtnOk.GetStyle();
// remove default push button style
style &= ~BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON;
// set the style
::SendMessage(m_BtnClose.GetSafeHwnd(), BM_SETSTYLE, (WPARAM)style, (LPARAM)TRUE);
```

Comment: How do I set Default Button to false?

Comment: I am not using resources, you can see the code I used to create the Button in my question.

Comment: Doh - sorry. Just eliminate BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON from the line for the OK button.

Comment: I have removed `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`, but the effect remained!

Comment: The dotted border is on the listview, how can that be the "default control"?

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, it's purpose is to indicate input focus. If you <kbd>Tab</kbd> around any native form, you'll see the rectangle jump around the indexes set up by the developer.

The reason it appears at all **is because it has a [TabStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx)**. As there is only one element in the first example, there's only one possibility for a tab stop, so it's indicated by the rectangle. Play around with the [TabStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx) property, <kbd>Tab</kbd> around, see what changes.